# Jquery eq() toggle all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, removechild

I'm using eq to get only a specific div, when I click on the "X" I should close the div specified. But what happens is that when I click on eq 0 it closes eq 1 and 2, and when I click on the div from eq 1 it closes eq 2. What can be happening?

```js
$('.' + tabHistoryBtn).eq(0).click(function() {
  $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(0).remove();
  $('.' + tabHistory).eq(0).remove();
});

$('.' + tabHistoryBtn).eq(1).click(function() {
  $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(1).remove();
  $('.' + tabHistory).eq(1).remove();
});

$('.' + tabHistoryBtn).eq(2).click(function() {
  $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(2).remove();
  $('.' + tabHistory).eq(2).remove();
});
```

Comment: We need more context into how these bindings are being generated.  Given that the variable is "tabHistoryBtn", my first thought was that you are keeping some sort of breadcrumb of the users interactions or something, in which case tab 3 was at one point tab 2, which was also at some point tab 1, and so on.  And it's possible you're binding these methods each time you make a new tab history, not unbinding the previous event listeners attached.

Comment: Any link that the user clicks will give a load of php content without reloading the page, and will create tabs to navigate between these contents, in the same function that creates a div where the newly generated content is and the tabs have the function call I want to use the tabs in the tabs, but I can not find the tabs in the tabs, so I can not use them. remove the tab (tabHistory). But every time I click on eq 0 remove 1 and 2, and on 1 remove 2 and 3!

Comment: It did not work, here is an example of the code only: http://jsfiddle.net/willianjohns/w5eLs8d4/

Comment: I used event.stopImmediatePropagation (); and solved one of my problems, now if I click close it just closes that div. But I discovered another problem, as I call the function of closing the tabs within the function of creating them, when I close for example the div eq 1, the div eq2 is no longer eq2 and yes eq 1, but it does not update, I believe should I change where to call the close tabs function, to update when eq should find them, how should I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any important commentary, and include all relevant code. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include your code in a runnable state, just like jsfiddle.